# getting the value of Message-ID from gmail imap with php

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I use standard imap functions to grab mails, I need to keep
track of the Message-ID (and References and In-Reply-To) to build
threads.
I reply to messages through the smtp, keeping the old subject, but in my web interface is not group them with others. If I add a In-Reply-To header - everything is OK.

The problem is that I can't get values of Message-ID, References, In-Reply-To (but in web interface they are present). 
I've tried different functions (imap_headerinfo, imap_fetchheader, imap_fetch_overview), but all of this values ​​are empty.

Please help!

Comment: Please show your code where you try and use `imap_headerinfo()`, `imap_fetchheader()` etc, as these functions are what you should use and should provide the information you want.

Comment: $this->mbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}', $email, $password);  
  
  
    print_r(imap_header($this->mbox, 1));  
    print_r(imap_fetch_overview($this->mbox, 1));  
    print_r(imap_fetchheader($this->mbox, 1));

Comment: I have opened a bounty on this question because I want to have access to this header information (specifically `Message-ID`) to make replying to an email via an IMAP server easy.

Comment: @CarterPape, I suggest starting a new question on the topic given you are adding so much information to the question that it wouldn't be the same question (and it's 2 years old).

Comment: @Joe I have just done so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727716/useful-imap-header-information-not-showing-up). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message ID is in a format like:

```
<OTJMCQtXnqgMaP1rLJi-cD9IvuH+xuVndE-DoWAZB0cbdffqHdw@mail.gmail.com>
```

which is parsed by the browser as an HTML tag, the following code will output a message ID in a way that can be displayed by the browser:

```
$this->mbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}', $email, $password);
$headers = imap_header($this->mbox, 1);
echo htmlentities($headers->message_id);
```

Or if you absolutely must use print_r:

```
$this->mbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}', $email, $password);
ob_start(); 
print_r(imap_header($this->mbox, 1));
print_r(imap_fetch_overview($this->mbox, 1));
print_r(imap_fetchheader($this->mbox, 1));
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: Just curious: did you look at the answer that I posted on my own question before coming here to write this answer? If so, no hard feelings; I didn't want the bounty to go to waste.

Comment: I saw your answer, but didn't realize you were the one offering the bounty.

Comment: Please don't fight :) Thanks for the useful advice. But where have you been 2 years ago? ))

Comment: Thanks for the question as well as the answer, did anyone figure how to fetch email overviews from `message_id` of an email , i am currently stuck up wanting to fetch mails in a thread through `references` which only returns `message ids` ?